# mac mysql workbench - in empty list creates deadlock

Tags: mysql-workbench

I think I have found a bug in MySQLWorkbench (mac version). The following SQL executed on a mac creates a deadlock:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn1=0 WHERE mycolumn2 IN ()
```

Obviously, the SQL is incorrect because there should be at least one value between the parenthesis. However, MySQLWorkbench hangs forever when that statement gets executed.

Comment: I can't replicate using OS X 10.11 with WB 6.3.4. However, bugs.mysql.com is the best place to report bugs.

Comment: Could it be that code completion hangs actually, not query execution?